# just in time debugger error when running windows application

Tags: c#

i run application from windows without visual studio 2010. I just run app.exe file and i get this error.

[image]

how can i disable this and get real error?

Comment: Disable it and get what? The application will crash, what error message are you going to get out of that?

Comment: You have an un-handled exception somewhere in your code. Hunt it down!

Comment: how to hunt it down if i don't know what error. i want to disable error and get real error message...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299272/net-debug-an-exe-that-crashes-immediately

Comment: Well, most of us hunt bugs down by stepping through code :) I guess you could try it too. Especially since you stated that you are running it from the development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Do what the message tells you - enable Just In Time debugging in Visual Studio, then you'll be able to see the actual problem.