# How to debug .net exe in the client side?

Tags: debugging

I have a .net exe installed in the client machine and it throws an exception..So how to debug and find the exact error..

Please note that 
1-this is not remote debugging..
2-I dont have log files to check and the machine is Windows 7..

Please let me know if this is possible?

As per comments:
As I already told I dont have log files to verify and I dont have any stackrace as well..

So anybody else know how to find the exact error..????

Comment: Assuming that the error only occurs on the client's computer, you are going to either need to put some logging into your executable so that you can have some visibility into what's going on, or install Visual Studio on the client's computer and perform your debugging there.

Comment: The exception thrown will have the error message and stack trace. Provided you don't swallow the exception, you should see this information which will be usefull to figure out what went wrong. By the way check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/2299302/1221319 it might be helpful in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the exe crashing (ie. the exception is unhandled) then if you are not able to install anything on the remote machine you will need to get a dump file from [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For a managed executable you should configure WER to [generate a full dump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as the minidump will likely not have enough information.

Once you have this dump file on your machine you can analyze it using WinDbg and the [SOS extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) (assuming you have a matching pdb file for the exe that generated the dump file)